# How to get back Google Instant in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, plugins

I use Windows 7 and want to know how to get back Google Instant in my browser.

Yesterday, Google changed the way of searching and included some new method to search. I used to be able to type away and see instant results. Pressing Enter would take me to a site. Now I have to click the mouse.

Is there any plugin for Google Chrome that will allow Instant search? I saw some plugins for Firefox, but didn't test them because I only use Google Chrome.

Comment: What does "some new method to search and watch not opened page" mean? Please clarify.

Comment: it is easy that you open google and see it, ... there is no more instant now you can only navigate to the page with mouse, before you can use keyboard and simply navigate down and arrow appear on the link, after pressing enter you are in page, now there is no that.

Comment: I think we need more clarification because your comment almost sounds like you want autocomplete which is wildly different than Google Instant. Google Instant doesn't require pressing enter.

Comment: @Rig No, pressing enter would take them to one of the found pages, not the actual search results. (If I understood correctly)

Comment: your answer was work before 2 days now when you "enable instant for fas..." nothing is happen, that options for now don't have any sense, i'm searching for some plugin that use instant searching, but it seems that plugin like those doesn't exist so far.

Comment: @slhck Sorry, you are correct. If you start with typing a web address it takes you to the site while still typing and if it isn't it takes you to the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for any plugin, because Google now includes an "automatic instant" feature with the arrow appearing after you press Enter in the search box. Now the searching looks like the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Click the wrench, options, then check the "Enable Instant for faster searching and browsing" box below the search engine drop down list to enable instant searches.

Comment: this doesnt work :(

Comment: @raptor Out of curiosity, what is the search engine you are using? My Google Instant does not appear to be working with Bing but it works with Google.

Comment: of course that i use google chrome